# What is the correct token for a multi value field?

Tags: rules, tokens

Oke, so I have this multi value field in drupal 7 and I want to use it's values in a custom php snippet in the rules module.

I found the [Array Tokens](http://drupal.org/project/token_array) module to generate an array of the values, but that is for Drupal 6.

Then I found [Architecture RFC: Field token architecture](http://drupal.org/node/1222592), which makes me assume I could use [node:field-name:0] or [node:field-name:value:0] to read the first entry, but I either replaces nothing of throws an error (I have tried various combinations).

Could someone tell me:

1. What is the right way to read a token with it's delta value?
2. How to get the delta of the fields so I can start a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the rules module gives you access to the $node object (if triggered on 'after saving content'). I managed to use it like this `$node->field_myField['und'][0]['value']`. Where `0` is the delta and `und` (probably) the language.

Since this looks like a multidimensional array I assume one could use a foreach on `$node->field_myField['und']`, but I did not test this.